# How to replace df.ix if .iloc and .loc don't seem to work?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to draw a map with Basemap following this tutorial: https://ramiro.org/notebook/basemap-choropleth/

This part of the code throws an error ('DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'):

```
if iso3 not in df.index:
    color = '#dddddd'
else:
    color = scheme[df.ix[iso3]['bin']]
```

Replacing with .iloc or .loc doesn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to retrieve the color from a list named `scheme` based on a column named `bin` with the index of that row, you can use the following:

```
n = df.iloc[iso3, 'bin']
color = scheme[n]
```

Comment: `df.iloc[iso3, 'bin']` ?

Comment: Is my answer helpful @rose-miller?